# IIS not redirecting to maped domain

Tags: windows, iis, server, iis-7

I have set up IP on BigRock for domain redirection and done binding at IIS. Now when I am browsing my Url it is showing me default site of IIS instead of my hosted one.

Please help me to suggest possible cases.

Comment: This is a tricky question,if you add more details to your question with examples (your binding of both websites),it would be great

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the IIS binding works

IIS binding has following IP:Port:Hostname

```
<bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

**Possibe cases**

1. So if you have two websites with bindings e.g
   **Ipaddress1:80:www.example.com** and **Ipaddress1:80:www.example2.com** ,then if the request reaches on Ipaddress1,then the first website will be served.**IPAddress comes how you have configured your DNS entry is**
2. You have two bindings but without the hostnames **Ipaddress1:80:** and **Ipaddress2:80:** ,then the request will be served if the IpAddress the request comes matches.So if the request comes on the second IpAddres,it will always be served by IIS no matter what the hostname is.
3. You can out a wildcard in the Ipaddress , *:80:www.example.com and *:80:www.example2.com .This means that IIS will listen for all the IPaddress.So iis will look at the hostname ([HTTP Host header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) and serves the website which matches the hostheader.This will be sent with the request by the browser

> A Host header field must be sent in all HTTP/1.1 request messages. A
>   400 (Bad Request) status code will be sent to any HTTP/1.1 request
>   message that lacks a Host header field or contains more than one.

getting your default website has possible causes

Your default website does not have a hostname configured and listens on IPAddress * and your actual website's IPAddress or hostname is not properly configured.So IIS serves the default website which has * IPaddress binding or no hostnames.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I have done all required settings but still not working. I think DNS redirection is not done properly by BigRock.

Comment: There is only one IP Address and I have configured hostname properly but still it is listening default website.

Comment: are you able to confim if the request is reaching your web server ? you can double check if IP is configured corretly with with any dns checking tool online

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dns record and specify a host header matching your domain name in IIS.

look here: http://www.visualwin.com/Host-Header/

Answer (score 0):

You should check the host header file, as that is the only thing needs to be changed.
I believe you have the same IP address mapped for different domain.

And still if it doesn't work please check IIS installed featured list and check the features not installed,  it should work.[image]

Comment: There is only one IP Address and I have configured hostname properly but still, it is listening default website.

Comment: Thank you Zain, You save my lots of time.